# Adding CRT library to other c++ IDE

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clion

I have been given an assignment to complete some C++ code. The problem is I use CLion for C++ work while the code has the CRT library from Visual Studio. The code I was given uses functions from the Visual Studio library. Is there a way to import Visual Studios 'CRT' library to CLion? I cannot build the code because of a compiler error due to the CRT functions in the given code.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: It is an undeclared variable error because the compiler does not have the CRT library which comes with the Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: The answer to your question is generally no, but if you actually post the error perhaps we can help with it.

Comment: If CLion is not using the Visual Studio toolchain then the answer is no.

Comment: drescherjm, what does toolchain mean? If it means the library is built into the IDE then I do not know. The CRT library is used for memory management.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toolchain

Comment: CLion is an IDE. I expect you can use Visual Studio as the toolchain.

Comment: Googling I found that the CLion IDE does not support Visual Studio as the toolchain. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206556469-What-compiler-debugger-can-I-use-within-CLion-

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess I will have to use Visual Studio to compile.